# how to configure a shared component using different .net framework versions in combination with git submodules

Tags: c#, .net, git

I have several projects/solutions sharing some dll's using git submodules. Now I have the situation the for one solution a submodule needs to be compiled with .net framework Version X and in another solution the same submodule must be compiled using .net Framework Version Y. Because this is the only difference I do not want to create two branches with the only difference being the target framework.
Is there another approach to solve this issue?